# POST request with OAuth1a and request body failed due to invalid signature

Tags: java, rest, oauth

I have the follow POST request with OAuth and a request body

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "firstname=martin");
Request request = new Request.Builder()
  .url("http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/people/new")
  .post(body)
  .addHeader("authorization", "OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\"5jyytn5guw84os48scckwkkwkkckwkowcgow04g04oc84kg0c4\",oauth_token=\"qwertzuiop\",oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\",oauth_timestamp=\"1465370390\",oauth_nonce=\"rFED5R\",oauth_version=\"1.0\",oauth_signature=\"aU2zedmum%2BwO3I%2FesAv159nLE8o%3D\"")
  .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
  .addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
  .build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

The problem is the request body (with form-urlencoded parameters) and the generated `oauth_signature`. Without the body my generated signature is absolutely correct and the call went fine, but after adding the request body the call failed with an `401 - unauthorized`

I thought that only the oauth header parameters are relevant for the oauth_signature calculation? I'm absolutely lost and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, obviously I was wrong. You actually have to take the body parameter into account for creating the signature.

> Next, gather all of the parameters included in the request. There are
>   two such locations for these additional parameters - the URL (as part
>   of the querystring) and the request body.

For everybody struggling with an issue similar to this I can recommend Twitters guideline for creating a signature and OAuth in general. See the following link

https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/creating-signatures